# Toolbox Theme Wordpress trying to change Post Date using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

thank you in advance for your help. Here is the site I am working on (it's in progress).

```
<block>http://66.147.244.96/~safeedu2/wordpress/blog/</block>
```

I am trying to change the post date css to be sans serif, about 10pt, and a dark grey color with no underline, but I am having trouble isolating it in the CSS. Using Chrome encoder I found I am trying to change this:

time.entry-date (Posted on)
span.sep (January 27, 2013)

Here is my css below:

```
/*
Theme Name: Toolbox
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/toolbox
Author: Automattic
Author URI: http://automattic.com/
Description: A semantic, HTML5, canvas for CSS artists and an ultra-minimal set of super-clean templates for your own WordPress theme development.
Version: 1.4
License: GNU General Public License
License URI: license.txt
Tags: custom-menu, sticky-post, microformats, rtl-language-support, translation-ready, full-width-template, post-formats

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/

/* =Structure
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#page {
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #404040;
    width: 1000px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px 4px #383737;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px 4px#383737;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 4px #383737;
}

#primary {
    width: 1000px;
}
#content {
    width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
#main .widget-area {
    display: none;
}
#colophon {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 75px;
    border-top: 2px solid #383737;
}

#colophon p {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    color: #959494;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 3px;
}

#colophon p a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    color: #f8931d;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#colophon img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 0;
}

#colophon h1 {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    color: #959494;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#colophon #block {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Homepage main marketing space Style */
#content #float {
    width: 193px;
    height: 193px;
    background-color: #f7941d;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#content #floatlast {
    width: 193px;
    height: 193px;
    background-color: #f7941d;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Newsletter Form Style */

input[type="submit"]{
    border: 1px dotted #f35d2a;
    font: helvetica;font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #f35d2a;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Increase the size of the content area for templates without sidebars */
.full-width #content,
.image-attachment #content,
.error404 #content {
    margin: 0;
}

/* Text meant only for screen readers */
.screen-reader-text,
.assistive-text {
    position: absolute !important;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}

/* Alignment */

.aligncenter {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #555555;
}

/* =Header
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#site-title {
    display: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#site-description {
    display: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}


/* =Menu
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#access {
    background: #404040;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 130px;
    background-image:url('http://66.147.244.96/~safeedu2/map/images/logo.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
}
#access ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 145px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#access li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 115px;
}
#access a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #404040;
    text-align: center;
}

#access a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    color: #f7931d;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
}

#access ul ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}

#access ul ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 115px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}

#access ul ul a {
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#525252), to(#404040));
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a {
    overflow: visible;
    text-align: center;
    width: 115px;
}
#access ul ul a:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    text-align: center;
    width: 115px;
}
#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    text-align: center;
    width: 115px;
}


/* =Content
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.sticky {
}
.entry-meta {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    clear: both;
}
.single-author .entry-meta .byline {
    display: none;
}

#content .entry-meta .time.entry-date {
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #404040;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#content .entry-meta span.sep {
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #404040;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#primary p {
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #404040;
}

#primary ul {
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #404040;
}

#primary li {
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #404040;
}

#primary li a {
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #404040;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#primary li a:hover {
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #f8931d;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#primary p strong {
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #f35d2a;
}

#primary h1 {
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #f15e2a;
}

#primary h2 {
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #f15e2a;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
}

#primary p a {
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #404040;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#primary p a:hover {
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #f8931d;
    text-decoration: none;
}



#content nav {
    display: none;
}
#content nav .nav-previous {
    display: none;
}
#content nav .nav-next {
    display: none;
}
#content #nav-above {
    display: none;
}
.paged #content #nav-above,
.single #content #nav-above {
    display: none;
}
#nav-below {
    display: none;
}
.page-link {
    display: none;
}
.page .edit-link {
    display: none;
}

.entry-title {
display: none;
}

.page-link {
display: none;
}

/* 404 page */
.error404 .widget {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.error404 .widget .widgettitle,
.error404 .widget ul {
    margin-right: 1em;
}
.error404 .widget_tag_cloud {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Notices */
.post .notice,
.error404 #searchform {
    background: #eee;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
}

/* Image Attachments */
.image-attachment div.entry-meta {
    float: left;
}
.image-attachment nav {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
.image-attachment .entry-content {
    clear: both;
}
.image-attachment .entry-content .entry-attachment {
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
.image-attachment .entry-content .attachment {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Aside Posts */
.format-aside .entry-header {
    display: none;
}
.single .format-aside .entry-header {
    display: block;
}
.format-aside .entry-content,
.format-aside .entry-summary {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
.single .format-aside .entry-content,
.single .format-aside .entry-summary {
    padding-top: 0;
}

/* Gallery Posts */
.format-gallery .gallery-thumb {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}

/* Image Posts */
.format-image .entry-header {
    display: none;
}
.single .format-image .entry-header {
    display: block;
}
.format-image .entry-content,
.format-image .entry-summary {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
.single .format-image .entry-content,
.single .format-image .entry-summary {
    padding-top: 0;
}


/* =Images
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

a img {
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
p img {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
/*
Resize images to fit the main content area.
- Applies only to images uploaded via WordPress by targeting size-* classes.
- Other images will be left alone. Use "size-auto" class to apply to other images.
*/
img.size-auto,
img.size-full,
img.size-large,
img.size-medium,
.attachment img,
.widget-area img,
.wp-caption {
    max-width: 100%; /* When images are too wide for containing element, force them to fit. */
    height: auto; /* Override height to match resized width for correct aspect ratio. */
}
img.alignleft {
    margin-right: 1em;
}
img.alignright {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
.wp-caption {
    padding: .5em;
    text-align: center;
}
.wp-caption img {
    margin: .25em;
}
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text {
    margin: .5em;
}
.gallery-caption {
}

.gallery {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.wp-smiley {
    margin: 0;
}


/* =Forms
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#searchform label {
    display: none;
}
#searchform input#s {
    width: 60%;
}
input[type=text],
input#s {
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
    width: 60%;
}
textarea {
    width: 80%;
}

/* Class for labelling required form items */
.required {
    color: #cc0033;
}


/* =Comments
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

article.comment {
    display: block;
}
#respond input[type=text] {
    display: block;
    width: 60%;
}
#respond textarea {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 80%;
}
#respond .form-allowed-tags {
    clear: both;
    width: 80%;
}
#respond .form-allowed-tags code {
    display: block;
}


/* =Widgets
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.widget {
    display: block;
}
.widget-area .widget_search {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.widget-area .widget_search input {
    float: left;
}


/* =Footer
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#colophon {
    padding: 1em 0 0;
}
```

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any rules targeting those selectors. Add this to your CSS:

```
time.entry-date 
{
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #222;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.entry-meta a 
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The first bit will target any `<time>` tags of class `entry-date`, while the second targets any `<a>` tags in a parent of class `entry-meta`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work! I can't seem to isolate it which makes me wonder if it is possible something I need to edit in the .php file? Here is a sample of that if that helps.

Comment: @leahdesigns - I added that code to the CSS file in Firebug and it worked fine. Have you actually added this to the CSS file for the theme? I just checked the site and now it looks like you added some rules (text-decoration: none, font-size: 11px, font-family: helvetica, sans-serif) to the time.entry-date selector....

Comment: Oh Jim, it was the dang cache. Now it works! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Lol, been bitten by that before!! Glad I could help :)